# package R does not exist when maven build my application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, r.java-file

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile 
    (default-cli) on project New_Sample: Compilation failure
[ERROR] workspace/New_Sample/src/main/java/com/samplepackge/New_Sample/HelloAndroidActivity1.java:
    [22,25] package R does not exist
```

HelloAndroidActivity1:

```
package com.samplepackge.New_Sample; 

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.*; 

public class HelloAndroidActivity1 extends Activity { 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }
}
```

Is there any idea about this... am already tried previous suggestions but am not get exact solution,Please help me

Comment: shouldn't your import be `import android.R;` instead of `R.`

Comment: Thank's for your response.am not import any R

Comment: what is at HelloAndroidActivity1.java:[22,25]

Comment: package com.samplepackge.New_Sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.*;
public class HelloAndroidActivity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    
}

Comment: `R.layout.activity_main` may be your project has some error and that is why R is not resolvable and it is thinking R is package name

Comment: but layout not contain any errors.it always shows package R does not exist.